# Form of minimax estimator

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, st.statistics, estimation-theory

Let $\Delta$ be the set of all probability distributions over $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,\ldots\}$ and fix some $\mathcal{P}\subseteq\Delta$.
Suppose additionally that $\Delta$ is endowed with some norm $||\cdot||$.
An *estimator* $\hat p_n$ for $\mathcal{P}$ is a mapping $\mathbb{N}^n\to\Delta$.
We say that $p_n^*$ is a *minimax optimal* estimator if
$$
\inf_{\hat p^n}\sup_{P\in\mathcal{P}} \mathbb{E}||\hat p_n(X_1,\ldots,X_n)-P||
=
\sup_{P\in\mathcal{P}} \mathbb{E}||p_n^*(X_1,\ldots,X_n)-P||,
$$
where the infimum is over all estimators
and the expectation is over $n$
independent copies of $X\sim P$.

I conjecture that $p_n^*$ can always be chosen to
be of the following form:
its $i$th coordinate is given by some function
$f_i:[0,1]\to[0,1]$
of the empirical frequency of the $i$th symbol,
$$
f_i: 
n^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^n1[X_j=i]
\mapsto [0,1],
$$
where the $f_i, i\in\mathbb{N}$
are fixed, deterministic, and
entirely determined by
$\mathcal{P}$ and are further
monotonically nondecreasing.
(For instance, if $\mathcal{P}=\Delta$
and $||\cdot||$ is either $\ell_1$
or $\ell_\infty$, then minimax optimality
is attained by the Maximum Likelihood Estimator,
where
the $f_i$ are the identity function.)

Question: Is this true? Known?

Update:
Václav Voráček provided what appears to be a counterexample:
$P(1)>0\implies P(2)=c$ for some constant $c$, for all
$P\in\mathcal{P}$, and $P(1)=0\implies P(2)=0$.

Hence I **additionally** assume that
$\mathcal{P}$ is permutation-invariant, in which case I conjecture that all of the $f_i$ can be taken to be identical.

Update II. I don't mind if $f$ is also a function of $n$ (in addition to the first argument, which is the empirical frequency) -- as long as it is monotone in the first argument.

Update III. Following some discussion (mostly with Václav), I'm making the conjecture more modest yet. Let's restrict $\mathcal{P}$ to those distributions $P$ for which $\sup_{i\in\mathbb{N}}P(i)(1-P(i))\le v$
and the norm $||\cdot||$ to be $\ell_\infty$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand\P{\mathcal P}\newcommand\N{\mathbb N}\newcommand\de{\delta}$You wrote:

> Hence I **additionally** assume that
> $\mathcal{P}$ is permutation-invariant, in which case I conjecture that all of the $f_i$ can be taken to be identical.

I do not think that this is true. For instance, suppose that $\P$ is the set of uniform distributions on subsets of $\N$ of cardinality $2$. That is, $P\in\P$ iff $P=P_{a,b}:=(\de_a+\de_b)/2$ for some distinct natural $a$ and $b$, where $\de_a$ is the Dirac probability measure supported on $\{a\}$.

Then I think a minimax estimator (which you referred to as "minimax optimal estimator") of $P$ does not exist. If we let
$$\hat p_n(a):=\frac1n\,\sum_{i=1}^n 1(X_i=a)$$
and replace $\N$ by $[N]:=\{1,\dots,N\}$ for a natural $N\ge2$, then I think a (randomized) minimax estimator of $P$ will be

- $P_{\hat a_n,\hat b_n}$ if $\{\hat a_n,\hat b_n\}=\hat A_n:=\{a\in[N]\colon \hat p_n(a)>0\}$ and the cardinality $|\hat A_n|$ of the set $\hat A_n$ is $2$ and
- $P_{\hat a_n,\hat c_n}$ if $A_n$ is a singleton set $\{\hat a_n\}$ and, given, $\hat a_n$, the point $\hat c_n$ is uniformly distributed over the set $[N]\setminus\{\hat a_n\}$.

Finally, I think the minimax risk will be attained in the limit as $N\to\infty$.

Hopefully, it is not exceedingly hard to verify the above claims.