# conjecture for general form of minimax estimator

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, st.statistics, estimation-theory

I had previously posed an overly ambitious version of this conjecture here,
[Form of minimax estimator](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/458264/form-of-minimax-estimator),
which was quickly shot down by Václav Voráček (on twitter) and Iosif Pinelis (MO answer in the link).

The current conjecture is more modest. First I'll restate the problem.

Let $\Delta$ be the set of all probability distributions over $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,\ldots\}$ and fix some $\mathcal{P}\subseteq\Delta$.

Assumptions on $\mathcal{P}$:

1. every $\mathcal{P}$ is permutation-invariant -- i.e., for every permutation $\Pi$
   on $\mathbb{N}$ and every $p\in\mathcal{P}$, we have $\Pi(p)\in\mathcal{P}$.
2. $\mathcal{P}$ is a convex set.

Suppose additionally that $\Delta$ is endowed with some norm $||\cdot||$.

An *estimator* $\hat p_n$ for $\mathcal{P}$ is a mapping $\mathbb{N}^n\to\Delta$.
We say that $p_n^*$ is a *minimax optimal* estimator if
$$
\inf_{\hat p^n}\sup_{P\in\mathcal{P}} \mathbb{E}||\hat p_n(X_1,\ldots,X_n)-P||
=
\sup_{P\in\mathcal{P}} \mathbb{E}||p_n^*(X_1,\ldots,X_n)-P||,
$$
where the infimum is over all estimators
and the expectation is over $n$
independent copies of $X\sim P$.

I will now state the conjecture, in a strong form and a weak form.

**Strong form**.
The minimax estimator
$p_n^*$ can always be chosen to
be of the following form:
its $i$th coordinate is given by some function
$f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$
of the empirical frequency of the $i$th symbol,
$$
f: 
n^{-1}\sum_{j=1}^n1[X_j=i]
\mapsto [0,1],
$$
where $f$
is fixed, deterministic, and
entirely determined by
$\mathcal{P}$ (and possibly $n$) and is further
monotonically nondecreasing.
(For instance, if $\mathcal{P}=\Delta$
and $||\cdot||$ is either $\ell_1$
or $\ell_\infty$, then minimax optimality
is attained by the Maximum Likelihood Estimator,
where
$f$ is the identity function.)

**Weak form**.
Same as the Strong form, with the additional conditions that
$||\cdot||=\ell_\infty$
and
$\mathcal{P}$ consists of all $p\in\Delta$ satisfying $p_i\le v$
for a given fixed $v$.

For both the strong and weak forms, I am also allowing *improper* estimators -- i.e.,
$\hat p_n$ whose range is not limited to $\Delta$.